# Material Angular - button style not rendering

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I'm not sure if I found a bug or if my configuration is off. My other components render and look like they're supposed to. But material angular's button styles are not loading right.

I'm using material angular and the issue is with the raised button from here https://material.angular.io/components/button/overview

Here is my markup

```html
<div class="nav-item">
    <button class="mat-raised-button"
        (click)="navToCreate()">            
        New Post
    </button>
</div>

<div class="nav-item">
    <button class="mat-raised-button" *ngIf="isLoggedIn === false" (click)="navToLogin()">
        <i class="material-icons md-48">account_box</i>
        <span>Login</span>
    </button>
</div>

<div class="nav-item">
    <button class="mat-raised-button" *ngIf="isLoggedIn === true" (click)="logOut()">
        <i class="material-icons md-48">account_box</i>
        <span>Logout</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

And here is what they render as 
[Pic of buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZqdK.png)

My app.module is the following

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

// Material components
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatSnackBarModule } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import { MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { MatTabsModule } from '@angular/material/tabs';
import { MatListModule } from '@angular/material/list';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';

// Components
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { DiscussionCardComponent } from './components/discussion-card/discussion-card.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { DiscussionDetailComponent } from './components/discussion-detail/discussion-detail.component';
import { SideMenuComponent } from './components/side-menu/side-menu.component';
import { DiscussionCreateComponent } from './components/discussion-create/discussion-create.component';
import { DiscussionDetailPageComponent } from './components/discussion-detail-page/discussion-detail-page.component';

import { TruncatePipe } from './pipes/truncate.pipe';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    DiscussionCardComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    DiscussionDetailComponent,
    TruncatePipe,
    SideMenuComponent,
    DiscussionCreateComponent,
    DiscussionDetailPageComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatButtonModule,
  ],
  exports: [],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your error is the `mat-raised-button` part. It is not a class, it is a property of the button.

`<button mat-raised-button>` is correct, `<button class="mat-raised-button">` is using a class

Comment: dumb's not the right word :P! we all went through it... and if you plan to later change the styles of Material's components you will need to read about ViewEncapsulation or the deprecated ng-deep. Hope you have fun with it :D